# Changing the color of a custom buttonshape programmatically

Tags: java, android, button, themes

I have a custom button shape that I am using for all of my buttons. I am trying to implement themes now but I can figure out how to automatically change the "solid" color of the buttons without getting rid of my custom shape. Can anyone let me know how to go about this? I've attempted to change the background colour of the button but I don't see any change; not sure why.

Here's my custom button shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="14dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="#D1D1D1"
    />
<size
    android:width="177dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="7dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF"
    />
</shape>
```

Comment: hi @rafvasq did my reply helped you? if so could you please accept my answer? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should assign an id to the xml file

then you just make recognize the Button by mean of findViewById

In the case you use multiple themes, you could use a case switch functionality

```
Button button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourbutton)

button.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.whatevercolor));   //or even better button.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF);
```